# What is the position of Whisper and Swarm in the Ethereum 2.0 Roadmap

Tags: swarm, whisper, serenity

Back in 2015, Ethereum vision was to be a "World Computer" relying on three main complementary technologies:

- **Ethereum** for decentralized Logic
- **Swarm** for decentralized Storage
- **Whisper** for decentralized Messaging

[image]

With **Ethereum 2.0** (Serenity) on its way composed of Casper FFG, Beacon chain, sharding, eWASM, I am wondering:

- Is the vision still the same or the triangular model may evolve based on the current Ethereum 2.0 development
- Is Swarm and Whisper development aligned with Ethereum 2.0